# Visual Studio Code - How to set (missing) Python kernel - Jupyter Notebook

Tags: python, macos, visual-studio-code, jupyter-notebook, pyenv

Background

- I am on macOS 12.6.1
- I installed pyenv via homebrew
- I installed 3.10.7 via pyenv `pyenv install 3.10.7`
- I set 3.10.7 to global with `pyenv global 3.10.7`
- I have installed ipykernel with `pip install ipykernel'
- My .zshrc file contains the following:

```
export PYENV_ROOT="$HOME/.pyenv"
command -v pyenv >/dev/null || export PATH="$PYENV_ROOT/bin:$PATH"
eval "$(pyenv init -)"
```

---

Under 'Python: Select interpreter' I have four options:

- Enter interpreter path...
- Use Python from 'python.defaultInterpreterPath' setting ~/.pyenv/versions/3.10.7/bin/python
- Python 3.10.7 64-bit('3.10.7':penv) ~/.pyenv/versions/3.10.7/bin/python **Recommended**
- Python 3.9.6 64-bit /usr/bin/python3 **Global**

---

If I type `python --version' in the terminal, I get Python 3.10.7

---

If I click on the kernel selection button (top right), I have the following option:

- Python 3.9.6 64-bit /usr/bin/python3 Currently selected **Suggested**
- Connect to a Jupyter Server

---

Could someone clarify/help me understand the interpreter vs kernel settings in Visual Studio Code?

How can I add the option of using Python 3.10.7 to the kernel?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've managed to get Python 3.10.7 to become available in the kernel option. What I did was:

1. File -> Open folder -> Desktop
2. Made a new python file, test.py, which contained some python code:

```
a = 4
b = 2
c = a + b
print(c)
```

3. Ran the python file, made sure that output (c) was printed.
4. Then cmd + shift + p + navigate to 'Jupyter filter kernels'
5. Selected 3.10.7 and unselected Python 3.9.6
6. Made a new jupyter notebook file, and the kernel option was already preselected as 3.10.7.

I don't know which part of my actions actually were required for it to get working, I'm sure that someone of them were not relevant, but it's working now.